# How can I detect when a user exit my app?

Tags: java, android, exit

I'm writing an android app and I want to remove the user from an array when he exit the app. I tried using the `onStop()` method, but it's not woking as I desire, because whenever an activity changes, the user is removed from the array.

I need a way to execute a method when the user has removed the app from "recent activities".
Any suggestions on the matter?

Comment: Have you considered [`onDestroy()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)?

Comment: Yes I tried that also, but when you remove the app from recent app it doesn't execute the method from `onDestroy()`.

Comment: @Candroid take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can track the back key so when the user presses it to exit the app you do what you want.

```
 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        //YOUR CODE HERE
    finish(); //<<<------MUST BE USED SO THAT THE BUTTON WILL ACTUALLY FINISH THE APP
        }
  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
```

Otherwise you can try the onPause() method instead of the onStop. Android doesnt recommend using the onStop to save data etc. I think though that the back key is best

Comment: OK thanks that can help me. I don't want to do anything with `onPause()`, since the user might get a call or accidently press the home button, so I dont want the app to throw him from the game.

But what about removing the app from the "recent activities"?
If the user removes the app from the "recent activities", how can I execute a method before it closes the app?

Comment: I think the only thing you can do is put a control boolean inside onKeyDown and use the onDestroy. What I mean is that if the back key is pressed it will make the boolean true. This way the onDestroy will do something only if the boolean is false because otherwise the onKeyDown did the job. If that doesnt work I think that you might need to change your approach completely.

Answer (score 0):

> I need a way to execute a method when the user has removed the app
>   from "recent activities"

When you swipe an app from the list, it actually just stops all the app's services (and not the app itself!). You may want to consider creating a service just for this purpose so that when the service is killed, you are notified via [onTaskRemoved](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved%28android.content.Intent%29).

You can read some more [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/20663)